# Ruby Checkbox with Icon now showing/hiding a div on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Forgive me for asking this question but I have been pulling my hair trying to fix this but I cannot understand where I am messing up. I have checked many answers on SO which recommend using attr or props in Jquery which did not work for me so I think I might be making some other problem.

### I have ruby code where I have an icon. When I click on this icon, I want to show/hide another div.

My ROR code:

```
<div class="choice <%= 'active' if listing.payment_term_shortterm == 'on' %>" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox">

    <%= form.check_box :payment_term_shortterm,  id: "payment_term_shortterm_test" %>

    <div class="card card-checkboxes card-hover-effect">
        <i class="ti-home"></i>
        <p>Small Time</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

This above thing creates this icon in my website as follows:

[image]

I just want that if Small Time is clicked it shows another div. My Jquery so far:

```
$(function () {
    $("#payment_term_shortterm_test").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#SmallTimeShow").show();
        } else {
            $("#SmallTimeShow").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

And this jquery is supposed to show following div:

```
<div id="SmallTimeShow" style="display: none;">

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
                <p> Hi Loan for Small time.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried many things, such as using props or attr in jquery but it also did not work.

EDIT

THis is what appears in the browser inspect element:

[image]

Comment: Are you using the default enabled [Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#turbolinks)? You can see this in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` by  checking if the `//= require turbolinks` statement is present.

Comment: No I am not using default turbolinks .   I have in my code   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,500,600", media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

Comment: I might have asked that question wrong. I'm not asking if you use the default turbolinks or customized version. I want to know if you have turbolinks enabled (which is the default case). With turbolinks enabled your statement `$(function () { ... })` might not fire, since it only executes on page refresh or if you navigate directly to the URL. With turbolinks enabled you should use [`document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() { ... }`](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#installing-javascript-behavior) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with display 'block' and display 'none' as I mentioned below:

```
$('#payment_term_shortterm_test').change(function() {
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#SmallTimeShow").css('display','block');
  }
  else{
    $("#SmallTimeShow").css('display','none');
  }       
});
```

Comment: Rails form creates its own ids for each input field. May be the problem arised with the id you applied on form field.

<%= form.check_box :payment_term_shortterm,  id: "payment_term_shortterm_test" %>

Can you please check your checkbox' id by running your app on browser & inspect over checkbox to check your checkbox-id. And then apply the same id to your checkbox.

Comment: If you can just get a brief look at it.